# Выборка суммы из двух таблиц по датам

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Помогите разобраться с ошибкой. Нужно выбрать по столбцу из 2 таблиц. Результирующие Столбцы представляют собой суммы от основных столбцов в каждой таблице. т.е. в 1 таблице 6 столбцов которые суммируются в 1 и во второй таблице 5 столбцов которые суммируются в 1. При этом выборка идет по дате - с такого то по такое то число из каждой таблицы происходит суммирование столбцов, вначале внутри каждой из таблиц а затем между 2 результирующими столбцами. Написал запрос для того что бы вывести 2 результирующих столбца :

```
SELECT 
col1, col2
FROM
(
SELECT 
    (SUM(`CA_USD`) + SUM(`CA_EUR`) + SUM(`CA_GBP`)) as col1, 
    DATEH
FROM
    `cashaccounts`
WHERE
    `orderKlient` = 'q111'
        AND
        (DATEH >= '2017-07-25' and DATEH <= '2017-07-26') 
union
        SELECT 
    (SUM(`Bond`) + SUM(`Fund`)) as col2,
    DATEH

FROM
    `paper`
WHERE
    `order` = 'q111'
        AND 
        (DATEH >= '2017-07-25' and DATEH <= '2017-07-26') 
        )x group by DATEH
```

Ожидалось получить 2 столбца из сумм столбцов каждой таблицы однако получаю ошибку :

> Unknown column 'col2' in 'field list'  0.000 sec

Подскажите как исправить запрос ? Использовать Join ?

Comment: `select ... as col1, NULL as col2,  DATEH ... union all select NULL, ... as col2,  DATEH ...`

Comment: @Mike благодарю, но уже сделал по другому

Comment: Ну left join поможет, только если в первой части всегда есть записи на какую то дату, а если на какую то дату записи будут только во торой части то такие строки не попадут в выборку. тут бы помог full outer join, но в MySQL его нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, надо было делать через `Left join`

```
SELECT 
cashaccounts.CA_AUD + cashaccounts.CA_EUR +
paper.Bond + paper.Fund as `value`
FROM
cashaccounts
    LEFT JOIN
paper ON cashaccounts.DATEH = paper.DATEH
WHERE
(cashaccounts.DATEH >= '2017-07-26' and cashaccounts.DATEH <= '2017-07-28') 
and cashaccounts.orderKlient = 'q111'
```

Answer (score 2):

Если вам надо два столбца сумм рядом с одной датой и даты в DATEH обеих таблиц всегда одинаковы, то вам нужно что-то такое(ниже).
Если вы не уверены, что даты всегда одинаковы - добавьте через UNION ALL обе таблицы c null, как предложил Mike в комментарии.
Могут быть тонкости, т.к. нам неизвестен формат столбца DATEH и нужно аккуратно их сравнивать.

```
SELECT (SUM(c.`CA_USD`) + SUM(c.`CA_EUR`) + SUM(c.`CA_GBP`)) as col1, 
(SUM(p.`Bond`) + SUM(p.`Fund`)) as col2, c.DATEH 
FROM `cashaccounts` as c 
JOIN `paper` as p ON c.DATEH = p.DATEH WHERE
    c.`orderKlient` = 'q111'
        AND
        (c.DATEH >= '2017-07-25' and c.DATEH <= '2017-07-26') 
        AND
    p.`order` = 'q111'
        AND 
        (p.DATEH >= '2017-07-25' and p.DATEH <= '2017-07-26')
```

Answer (score 1):

UNION добавляет строки в выборку, в те же столбцы что и в первом SELECT.
Все значения col2 из второго запроса попадают в col1. Столбца col2 в результирующей выборке нет.